# Query on scraping multiple pages using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape a page using beautifulsoup from the website link - `https://concreteplayground.com/auckland/events`.
I was able to extract everything from page-1.when i wanted to move on next page I couldn't find any reference to link/parse next page.I tried inspecting the page and when I check for moving onto page 2 i find the content as follows -

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="page-numbers" href="">2</a>
```

I am not really sure how to handle this type of web pages.It would be great if someone can help me out with this.The next page content is being fetched and displayed in the same url.not sure whats going on in the background as well.
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the trash answer previously. I got all caught up with discovering selenium's click function haha. Anyway, the page you want is Ajax heavy and needs a different approach as opposed to traditional HTML scraping. Please refer the below link to learn more about what URL you have to handle on the following link: [Handling Ajax](http://toddhayton.com/2015/03/11/scraping-ajax-pages-with-python/). So basically, a script is run which allows pagination without changing the main URL.

The below is my attempt to achieve the output you asked for. Would really appreciate it if anyone finds improvements to streamline it.

```
#Import essentials
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#Not necessary, but always useful just in case
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36'}


#Read url, parse using BeautifulSoup, and dynamically find no of pages
temp_page = requests.get('https://concreteplayground.com/auckland/events', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup (temp_page.content, 'html.parser')
PgNos = len(soup.findAll('li', {'class':'page'}))


#Now for the interesting part!

#Form the url to which requests are to be sent. This url is used to GET every json response which I've later parsed and printed. This url is available in the network tab of developer tools of your browser (like Firebug)
for i in range(PgNos+1):
    u = 'https://concreteplayground.com/ajax.php?post_type=tribe_events&place_type=event&region=auckland&sort=all&paged='
    r = str(i)
    l = '&action=directory_search&user_lat=&user_lon='
    url = u+r+l
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = response.json()

    #Now,iterate through the main body of the json to get what you want
    for each in data['results']:

        event_name = each['post_title']
        event_excerpt = each['post_excerpt']

        #There's a li'l HTML bit here, so you ought'a use BS to parse that. 
        rdata = each['info']
        raw = BeautifulSoup(rdata, 'lxml')
        date = raw.p.text
        rawvenue = raw.findAll('span', {'itemprop':'name'})
        venuename = rawvenue[0].text
        venueaddress = rawvenue[0].meta['content']

        #Obviously, you can also write to a file in lieu of the below. 
        print ('Event : ' + event_name + '\n' + 'Excerpt : ' + event_excerpt + '\n' +'Date : ' +  date + '\n' + 'Venue : ' + venuename + '\n' + 'Address : ' + venueaddress + '\n\n')
```

These sources were also useful during the reconstruction of my answer: [GET and POST explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-post-requests-using-python/) and [JSON iteration](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/2x145u/how_to_iterate_through_this_dictionary/?st=jhmkrk4z&sh=373c3076).